# How to use russian letters in object names and filenames in Blender?

Tags: interface

I don't want this

[image]

21st century is now. Every app should be multilingual out of the box. How to teach Blender to accept russian letters?

No patches accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blender does not currently support unicode in the file browser. Sorry to disappoint.

~Dan